# "Error: A connect request was made on an already connected socket"

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am trying to write a program which will request certain pieces of information, for example the internal temperature, from a camera which acts as a server, sorry if my terminology is off, but basically what I mean is that communication with the camera is achieved through HTTP get requests.  The program essentially just calls an slightly adapted version [async_client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp) from the boost library passing in a different path each time to check a different value, then compares the returned value to ensure it sounds reasonable before passing in a different path to check something else.

The code seems to work correctly the first time round, but on the second attempt it gets to the handle_connect function and outputs "Error: A connect request was made on an already connected socket"

Here is what the function looks like:

```
void Async_client::handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& err, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
  {
        http_deadline_timer_.cancel();
        if (!err)
        {
            // The connection was successful. Send the request.
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_, request_, boost::bind(&Async_client::handle_write_request, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            //deadline timer stuff
            http_deadline_timer_.expires_from_now( ::boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            http_deadline_timer_.async_wait( ::boost::bind(&Async_client::call_handle_deadline_timeout, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else if (endpoint_iterator != tcp::resolver::iterator())
        {
            // The connection failed. Try the next endpoint in the list.
            socket_.close();
            tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
            socket_.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Async_client::handle_connect, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
            //deadline timer stuff
            http_deadline_timer_.expires_from_now( ::boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            http_deadline_timer_.async_wait( ::boost::bind(&Async_client::call_handle_deadline_timeout, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            LOG_WARN("Async_client.cpp: Error: " << err.message()); 
        }
  }
```

I tried copying this section of code from the else if statement into the else statement as well thinking that it would close the socket and re-run the handle_connect function, but it just seems to crash to software on endpoint= *endpoint_iterator line.

```
socket_.close();
            tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
            socket_.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&Async_client::handle_connect, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++endpoint_iterator));
```

Does anyone have any idea what I should do in this situation?  Disconnect the socket and reconnect?  If so how do I do this?

Comment: At the start of the first function I added socket_.close(); to close the socket each time the async_client is used.  Thankfully this didn't seem to disrupt anything the first time async_client was called, and on the second run through it did seem to let it get past the handle_connect function, however it only gets as far as handle_read_status_line where it reads the response_stream as 0, which is an invalid response, in the first run through of the program the response_stream was 0x23f350.  Are these problems related?  Any idea what I can do about it?

Comment: Think I've managed to fix the problem by adding "response_.consume(response_.size());" at the start of the first function immediately after the socket_.close(); line.  This clears the clearing response_ which is a boost::asio::streambuf.

@Sam Miller: what did you edit about my post?  It doesn't really matter I guess, but if I did something wrong about the way I asked my question it would be good to know for next time. Thanks.

Comment: @meerkat look at the change log. I removed your valediction and added the boost-asio tag. If you have solved your question, please add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `SO_REUSEADDR` option with `setsockopt` could help.